# How can i execute a function many times while press a button?

Tags: reactjs

How can i execute the function while is pressed the button?

```
<div onMouseUp={up} onMouseDown={()=>down('element')}  >
```

these is my interval functions:

```
const update=(val) =>{
    add(val) 
  }

  const down=(val) =>{
    value = 0
    interval = setInterval(update(val), 100)
  }

  const up=() =>{
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
```

but never stop the execution, what is the wrong?

i was trying with states: but dont worked too

```
const [myInterval, setMyInterval] = useState(null)
 
  const update=(prop) =>{
    handleAdd(prop) 
  }

  const down=(prop) =>{
    setMyInterval(setInterval(update(prop), 100)) 
  }

  const up=() =>{
    clearInterval(myInterval)
  }
```

Comment: If this is in a react component, it's probably because `interval` is not stateful and will be reinitialized by the time `up` is called

Comment: You could store the ```interval``` in some state then clear the interval ```onMouseUp```. Right now your interval is out of scope for the up function. You could also achieve this with ```refs```

Comment: @KyleLambert can you create your answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using [`useEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) (with cleanup) to manage the interval, triggered by a boolean `running` state value which is toggled `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp`.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
  const [running, setRunning] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (running) {
      const countTimer = setInterval(() => {
        setCounter(c => c += 1);
      }, 500);

      return () => clearInterval(countTimer);
    }
  }, [running])

  const toggleRunning = () => {
    setRunning(!running);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{counter}</div>
      <button type='button' onMouseDown={toggleRunning} onMouseUp={toggleRunning} >Hold down to run counter</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```